# How to solve the No module named bootstrap_date_picker_plus error?

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

I am using Django 3.2.3 and I would like in my app to use date picker using the package `bootstrap_datepicker_plus`. I have installed it and added it following the steps in the link https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus/. However, when I run the app, I am getting the error **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrap_datepicker_plus**. When I checked in the installed packages, I noticed that the bootstrap_date_picker_plus package is installed as it is shown in the attached image [image]

Comment: Your virtual env is activated ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Look at the attachment, please.